# Loop through a directory and zip every 50 files together in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, zip

I'm sure there is probably a better way to do this but I am trying to loop through a directory and zip together every 50 files. It works for most of the files, but messes up when it gets to the last 49 files.

I would like to tell it to still zip those 49 files together.

Here if my code:

```
import os 
from zipfile import ZipFile
from os import walk

current_directory = os.getcwd()
total = 0
cnt = 0
zip_list = []
name_count = 0 

for f in os.listdir(current_directory)
    total+=1

for f in os.listdir(current_directory):
    cnt+=1

    if f.endswith('Z') and len(zip_list) <= 50:
        zip_list.append(f)

        if len(zip_list) == 50:
            name_count+=1
            with ZipFile('zip'+str(name_count), 'w') as myzip:
                for f in zip_list:
                    myzip.write(f)
            del zip_list[:]
```

Comment: What is the question?. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  You should spend some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need too many tracking variables there if you only need 50-50 chunks from the list then just append all the files in the list and then split it up into equal size chunks of 50 :

```
for item in range(0,len(zip_list),50):
    chunks.append(zip_list[item:item+50])

for index,chunk_1 in enumerate(chunks):
    with ZipFile(str(index) + '.zip', 'w') as myzip:
        for files in chunk_1:
            myzip.write(files)
```

> the modified version of your  code :

```
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
from os import walk

current_directory = os.getcwd()
zip_list = []
chunks=[]

for f in os.listdir(current_directory):

    if f.endswith('Z'):
        zip_list.append(f)


for item in range(0,len(zip_list),50):
    chunks.append(zip_list[item:item+50])

for index,chunk_1 in enumerate(chunks):
    with ZipFile(str(index) + '.zip', 'w') as myzip:
        for files in chunk_1:
            myzip.write(files)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a bit more code after the end of the last loop (outside the loop) like:

```
if len(zip_list) > 0:
    name_count += 1
    with ZipFile('zip' + str(name_count), 'w') as myzip:
        for f in zip_list:
            myzip.write(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly ,here is a different approach:

```
import os 
from zipfile import ZipFile
from os import walk

current_directory = os.getcwd()
total = 0
cnt = 0
zip_list = []
name_count = 0 

file_names = os.listdir(current_directory)
file_count = len(os.listdir(current_directory))

while cnt<file_count:
    zip_list = []
    if file_count-cnt>49:
        zip_list = file_names[cnt:cnt+50]
        cnt = cnt+50
    else:
        zip_list = file_names[cnt:]
        cnt = file_count
    name_count +=1
    with ZipFile('zip'+str(name_count), 'w') as myzip:
        print zip_list
        for f in zip_list:
            myzip.write(f)
```